# Removing HIDDEN ERROR string

Tags: string, mongodb, replace

I grabbed(using my script) known people bio in wiki. and noticed some data to have this lines:

> HIDDEN ERROR: Usage of "spouse" is not recognized
>
> HIDDEN ERROR: Usage of "children" is not recognized

Other bio have this:

> HIDDEN ERROR: Usage of "spouse" is not recognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage
>   of "children" is not recognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage of "signature" is
>   not recognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage of "death_cause" is not
>   recognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage of "parents" is not recognizedHIDDEN
>   ERROR: Usage of "resting_place" is not recognized

I was doing string.replace().

```
var start = oldString.indexOf("HIDDEN ERROR");
var end = oldString.indexOf("not recognized");
var toRemove = oldString.substring(start, end);
var newString = oldString.replace(toRemove, ""));
```

but can't get rid of the unwanted lines. What is the best way to remove those lines?

I used mongodb to save the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like JavaScript. Is it? Then just use `var newString = oldString.replace(/HIDDEN\s+ERROR:\s+Usage\s+of\s+"[^"]*"\s+is\s+not\s+recognized/g, "");`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D59B1c/1).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regex to remove these substrings:

```
/HIDDEN\s+ERROR:\s+Usage\s+of\s+"[^"]*"\s+‌​is\s+not\s+recognize‌​d/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D59B1c/1).

Note all the literal spaces are matched with `\s+` that matches *one or more whitespace chars* including line breaks and tabs. `[^"]*` matches *zero or more symbols other than `"`* since `[^...]` is a **negated character class**.

```js
var rx = /HIDDEN\s+ERROR:\s+Usage\s+of\s+"[^"]*"\s+is\s+not\s+recognized/g;
var str = "TEXT: <HIDDEN ERROR: Usage of \"spouse\" is not recognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage\nof \"children\" is not recognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage of \"signature\" is\nnot recognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage of \"death_cause\" is not\nrecognizedHIDDEN ERROR: Usage of \"parents\" is not recognizedHIDDEN\nERROR: Usage of \"resting_place\" is not recognized>";
str = str.replace(rx, '');
console.log(str);
```